# Independence in Belief Networks

Tags: bayesian-network

The belief network for the following questions is given below:

[image]

**Q1: Which variables must be independent of A given C and S according to the belief network above?**

My ans:

Since C is given, there is no active trail through A-C-D, hence D is independent of A.

Since C is given, there is an active trail through A-C-B, hence B may be dependent on A.

Since B may be dependent on A and E is dependent on B, E may be dependent on A.

Therefore, the only variable independent of A is D.

**Q2: Which variables must be independent of A given D and S according to the belief network above?**

My ans:

C is dependent on A.

Since D is given, there is no active trail through C-D-E.

There is no active trail through A-C-B.

Therefore, both B and E are independent of A.

Would really appreciate it if someone can verify whether my reasoning and answers are correct. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: In your proposed solution for $Q1$, don't you conclude that the only variable independent of $A$ is $D$?

Comment: No problem.  For $Q2$, perhaps I've forgotten what the notation means, but is it not the case that knowing $A,D$ occurred gives me some information regarding $C$, and information regarding $C$ gives me information regarding $B$, no?

Comment: As I am testing whether or not $A,B$ are independent, I can assume that $A$ occurred.  that is to say, if $A$ occurs then we have learned something about $C$, and knowing something about $C$ surely tells me something about $B$.

Comment: Suppose, for instance, that, given $A$, $C$ occurs with probability $.01$ and that given $B$, $C$ occurs with probability $.99$   In that case, given $A$, I really don't think $C$ is terribly likely, so I therefore don't think $B$ is terribly likely.  So information about $A$ can tell me something about $B$.

Comment: Does the notation require that $A,B$ are independent?  Otherwise, I think my example works.  But, as I say, I am not really clear on what the notation implies.